# Find out values from all keys without mentioning which particular key in tcl

Tags: json, tcl

I am very new to tcl. In my implementation, my input is a nested-json file. I need to store the values along with the keys in a txt file.
I converted the json file to dict and then by using *jsonget* from http://wiki.tcl.tk/13419, I could provide the keys and found out the values of each key iteratively very easily.
Now, my problem is, my json file might get updated later. Hence, I will not know which key has been added in the json, thus I will not be able to get the values too.
My code must be generic and must apply to all these dynamic json files and it must be able to give all these keys and along with their values.

For example

```
{"test":[{"a":1,"b":2}]} }

result: 
a 1
b 2

{"test":[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}]}

result: 
a 1 
b 2
c 3

{"test":[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":[{"d":4,"e":5}]]}

result: 
a 1
b 2
c d 4 
  e 5
```

All this, without requiring any change in the code. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You're already storing the data in a dict. `set d [json::json2dict { {"test":[{"a":1,"b":2}]} }];  dict keys [lindex [dict get $d test] 0]` gives you the list `a b`  What are you looking for?

Comment: My question is: If "a":"1" is simply given, the code must find out "a" is the key and 1 is its value .. on its own. If the json file gets changed later and more key-value pairs are entered like "b":"2". and so on, the code must be able to figure out the new keys and their values on their own without me having to change the code.

Comment: Are you just looking to print out the structure like you show, or do you want to do something specific with the key:value pairs? I still don't understand how the Tcl code you've been given is *not* meeting your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Neither your example, nor your wording ("requirement") are particularly helpful. I can only second-guess on your intentions: Do you want to know how to write a piece of Tcl that processes selected content of the JSON document in a generic (regular) manner, repeatedly, without knowledge about its structure or actual literal content (e.g., key labels)?

### If yes, ...

... does this help?

```
proc foo {json} {
    foreach k [dict keys [lindex [dict get $json test] 0]] {
       puts "$k => [jsonget $json test 0 $k]"
    }
}

foo [json::json2dict { {"test":[{"a":1,"b":2}]} }];

foo [json::json2dict { {"test":[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}]} }];

foo [json::json2dict { {"test":[{"a":1 }]}}];
```

It does not add much to what glenn has pointed you to.

### If no, ...

... refine your example, wording.

### General recommendation

For serious JSON-based development, consider [rl_json](https://github.com/RubyLane/rl_json) or [tdom](https://tdom.github.io/).

Comment: Or you could `set d [json::json2dict ...]; set subdict [jsonget $d test 0]; dict for {key val} $subdict {puts "$key => $val"}`

Comment: Hope this edit helps. Your code gives only the values, I need the keys too.

Comment: Well, my edit includes them. Are you sure that you know what you are after and why? Do you really know how to read a Tcl script? Besides, a @glennjackman hints at, there would be nicer ways of doing what you are after ... but who knows ...

Comment: rl_json is highly recommended; it's designed for scaling up to very large documents.

Comment: I took some time to understand as I am very very new to this. The solution applies well. Thanks for telling about rl_json, it will help greatly in a later part of my problem at hand